# Detecting period patterns in time series data

Tags: time-series, signal-processing

Suppose I have a large dataset of my transaction history (the date, the amount). I want to identify transactions which are recurrent (e.g. my phone bill every month, my rent every week, etc.) from the dataset. Note that the time period of recurrence may not alway be the same (e.g. rather than exactly every 15 days, we may sometimes have 13/14/16 days says between a occurrences of particular recurrent transaction).

It there a good statistical method which would allow me to do this (and perhaps also predict these recurrent transactions forward in time)? I suspect there might be sometime in time series literature but I am not familiar with concepts in this area.

Comment: This can be done using spectral analysis.

Comment: Could you explain more please? I am not familiar with spectral analysis.

Comment: Spectral analysis filters out the periodic components in the series.  That would be all the sinusoidal terms.